# itextpdf exception when closing document with JFreeChart added

Tags: java, exception, itext, jfreechart

I am trying to add a JFreeChart to my PDF file and am getting a exception deep in the bowels of itextpdf. I have no clue what I am doing wrong or what the exception is really telling me. Here is my code segment:

```
try {
            PdfWriter writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(filePath.getText()));
            document.open();
            document.add(setParagraph("Stoker Monitor Report",titleFont));
            document.add(setParagraph(name.getText(),subTitleFont));
            document.add(setParagraph(date.getText(),dateFont));
            PdfContentByte cb=writer.getDirectContent();
            Float height=7.f;
            Float width=11.69f;
            PdfTemplate tp=cb.createTemplate(width,height);
            Graphics2D g2D=new PdfGraphics2D(cb,width,height);
            Rectangle2D r2D=new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,width,height);
            Chart.getInstance().getChart().draw(g2D,r2D);
            tp.addTemplate(tp, 0, 0);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | DocumentException e1) {
            System.err.println("Unable to open "+filePath.getText()+" for writing");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        document.close();
```

The exception is on the close. Here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.IllegalPdfSyntaxException: Unbalanced save/restore state operators.
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.sanityCheck(PdfContentByte.java:4193)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.reset(PdfContentByte.java:1813)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.reset(PdfContentByte.java:1801)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.resetContent(PdfWriter.java:746)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.endPage(PdfDocument.java:1061)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:882)
at com.itextpdf.text.Document.close(Document.java:415)
at stokerMonitor.CreateReport$CreateButtonListener.actionPerformed(CreateReport.java:152)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have no idea what this means since it involves none of my code. I assume that there is something in the parameters that I am passing that is causing this but I have no idea what to look at. Can some please interpret this exception for me and point me in the right direction? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot one line when you copied your code from who knows where:

```
PdfTemplate tp=cb.createTemplate(width,height);
Graphics2D g2D=new PdfGraphics2D(cb,width,height);
Rectangle2D r2D=new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,width,height);
Chart.getInstance().getChart().draw(g2D,r2D);
g2D.dispose();
cb.addTemplate(tp, 0, 0);
```

Without the `dispose()`, you can get all kinds of weird errors.

Also `tp.addTemplate(tp, 0, 0);` should be `cb.addTemplate(tp, 0, 0);`

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of the error but I get nothing for the output. Back to the drawing board on that. Anyway I didn't exactly forget, I just didn't realize it was necessary. I figured that object would be released with normal garbage collection when the thread ended.

Comment: When you create a `PdfGraphics2D` object, the `saveState()` method is called to save the graphics state before it's changed due to drawing instructions. The `dispose()` method calls the `restoreState()` method to restore the state to whatever it was before you started drawing. You always need to restore the state for every save state operation, otherwise the PDF syntax is wrong. It's not related to garbage collection but necessary for the consistency of the PDF syntax.

Comment: Upon second inspection, I see why nothing is visible. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that part out. Although I am rotating the page for landscape I guessed that I had to switch height and width which is wrong. Using the correct values I am getting a partial chart on a new page. I think I now need to play with the size and position to get it where I want it. Thanks again.